# Strange behavior anti-aliasing filter ray tracer

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, antialiasing, raytracing

I have a simple ray tracer implemented in C++. What I am doing is implementing an anti-aliasing filter as explained here at page 230:

http://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/books/fcg2/rt.pdf

I am using a 4x4 grid with 16 regular samples but the result is a bit weird:

normal ray tracer

[image]

ray tracer with anti-aliasing

[image]

I can't figure out why I have this kind of problem.. may you help me? thanks in advance!

EDIT: here you have some code:

```
int RAY_DISTRIBUTION = 4;
Vec3<float> px_color;
for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_WIDTH; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < WINDOW_HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < RAY_DISTRIBUTION; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < RAY_DISTRIBUTION; l++)
            {
                Vec3<float> rayDir = camera->pixelToWorld(i, j, (k + 0.5f) / RAY_DISTRIBUTION, (l + 0.5f) / RAY_DISTRIBUTION, 0, 0) - camera->position;
                px_color = px_color + distributedRayTracer->trace(camera->position, rayDir, 0) * 255; //remap to [0,255]
            }
        }
        px_color = px_color / pow(RAY_DISTRIBUTION, 2);
        g_image->setPixel(i, j, qRgb(px_color.x, px_color.y, px_color.z));
    }
}

Vec3<T> pixelToWorld(int i, int j, T offset_x, T offset_y, T jitter_dx, T jitter_dy)
{
    float fov = 30;
    float angle = tan(PI * 0.5 * fov / 180.);

    T remapped_x = (2 * ((i + offset_x + jitter_dx) / WINDOW_WIDTH) - 1) * angle * (WINDOW_WIDTH / WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    T remapped_y = (1 - 2 * ((j + offset_y + jitter_dy) / WINDOW_HEIGHT)) * angle;

    Vec3<T> w = position - lookAt;
    w.normalize();
    Vec3<T> u = up.cross(w);
    u.normalize();
    Vec3<T> v = w.cross(u);
    v.normalize();

    Vec3<T> transf = -u*remapped_x + v*remapped_y - w;
    transf.normalize();

    return position + transf;
}
```

Comment: We need some code, please. Show us how your processing is done.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an int overflow (e.g. 256->0) in your code? These bugs typically lead to black spots in white areas in rendering/image processing contexts. (As seen on the lamp on the top side of the cube.)

Comment: @Ninetainedo you are right! Just edited my post

Comment: You should try to log each value returned by `distributedRayTracer->trace(camera->position, rayDir, 0) * 255` to check for overflow.

Comment: @anderas you were right! Thanks a lot! some values are slightly greater than 255, is it "fair" to put them back in the range setting them to 255 or this phenomenon shoudn't happen? Since there is actual no answer should I delete my question or leave it like this?

Comment: @Ninetainedo you were right as well! Couldn't tag you in the previous comment unfortunately

Comment: For your question, I use to clamp the values in my own RayTracer (keep them between bounds). But there are others algorithms showing better results.